# expo react native app stuck on refreshed when I run the app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on an expo project when I run the app It stuck on Refreshed

[image]

Comment: Is your expo project in a real time file replicated directory like OneDrive or DropBox? Those can sometimes spend a lot of time touching files while you code and causing endless refreshes.

Comment: Okay, thanks! @Atmas for your help you save my week.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to link to the expo resource that I found that talks about it in a separate Answer so people can quickly see the resolution. Can you mark my answer as resolved and also add a comment in it to exactly which one matches your case and how you fixed it, so myself and others can learn directly from what your exact experience was and how you exactly fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion in comments, Expo server refreshes are frequently triggered by real-time replication/backup software running on the computer, especially apps like OneDrive or DropBox.

More good information is documented here on expo's forum:
https://forums.expo.io/t/infinite-refreshing-without-doing-anything/2119

Comment: Also unrelated to this particular resolution, for posterity, I personally have noticed that a module in VsCode might also be triggering a lot of these loops even when not explicitly saving anything, but have not nailed down an exactly resolution for it. I suspect the JS/TSX extension or some other internal library is probably sporadically touching/compiling in order to support its own functionality under the covers.